# Exact values of $x$ for $2\cos^2x=1+\sin x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

This question involves finding the exact values of $x$ such that $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 2\pi$.  So far I have subtracted everything to the left side of the equation and then used the pythagorean identities to change $2\cos^2x\ \ \text{to}\ \ 2-2\sin^2x$, leaving

$$2-2\sin^2x-\sin x-1=0\,.$$
However, I need to further factor this, and I am not sure about what to do next.  Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\sin x=u; \sin^2x=u^2
$$

Comment: Using the quadratic formula I got x= 1/2 and x=-1, is this correct?

Comment: No, you got $u=\frac{1}2;u=-1$, which means $sin(x)=\frac{1}2;sin(x)=-1$

Answer (score 0):

$2\cos^2x=1+\sin x$ becomes $2\sin^2 x+\sin x-1=0$ with the Pythagorean theorem

quadratric formula gives you the equations: $\sin x_{1;2}={{-1\pm 3}\over 4}=\frac 1 2;-1$ whose solutions are:

1) $\sin x=\frac 1 2$

$x=\frac {\pi} 6+2k\pi;\frac 5 6\pi+2k\pi$

2)$\sin x=-1$

$x=\frac 3 2\pi+2k\pi$